# How can I see what origin/upstream/latest is pointing to at the origin?

Tags: git

I have checked out a distro-specific source of a program, specifically:

```
git clone https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/eog.git
```

I want to find out where is the `upstream` repository (containing the code that is not distro-specific) from the point-of-view of the remote repository.

When I do `git log`, one of the lines I get is the following:

```
commit [hash] (tag: upstream/45.3, origin/upstream/latest)
```

The last part (`origin/upstream/latest`) gives me hope that what I want to do is possible, but I'm not completely sure.

I tried this:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/eog.git (fetch)
origin  https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/eog.git (push)
```

As you can see, it does not give me what I want (I want the upstream URL, from the point-of-view of the remote repo).

I tried this:

```
$ git branch --remote
  origin/HEAD -> origin/debian/latest
  origin/debian/bookworm
  origin/debian/jessie
  origin/debian/latest
  origin/debian/master
  origin/pristine-tar
  origin/ubuntu/latest
  origin/upstream/3.14.x
  origin/upstream/3.38.x
  origin/upstream/latest
  origin/wip/3.38.3
```

Which gives me hope, but it's not what I want. What it tells me is that there is a remote branch called `upstream/latest` at my `origin`, which is the URL I know.

The following confirms it:

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/eog.git
  Push  URL: https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/eog.git
  HEAD branch: debian/latest
  Remote branches:
    debian/bookworm tracked
    debian/jessie   tracked
    debian/latest   tracked
    debian/master   tracked
    pristine-tar    tracked
    ubuntu/latest   tracked
    upstream/3.14.x tracked
    upstream/3.38.x tracked
    upstream/latest tracked
    wip/3.38.3      tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    debian/latest merges with remote debian/latest
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    debian/latest pushes to debian/latest (up to date)
```

I guess "tracked" here means that my local repo is tracking those remote branches. But my suspicion is that the remote repo uses those branches, `upstream/latest` in particular, to track another branch that is remote from the point-of-view of *my* remote repo.

**Question: What is the URL of the `upstream` remote, from the point-of-view of my `origin` remote? Is this information accessible from inside my local repo using the git CLI and if so how do I access it?**

Comment: You can't get it that way.... having a reference called `origin/upstream/something` and having `origin` being a remote means that in _that_ remote there is a **local** branch called `upstream/something`..... other than that, I don't think you can get information (through git) about the remotes of a repo that is not local.

Comment: Agreed with @eftshift0, this is a confusion induced by mere names. The repo itself doesn't contain references to its remotes' remotes.

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of as well :) But it *feels* like it should be possible. Do you have pointers to any documentation that states this limitation? I read through https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches but I see nothing relevant.